# Redux Framework - How To Validate Phone Number

Tags: regex, validation, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the [Redux Framework](http://reduxframework.com) to build a theme options panel for a Wordpress theme.

I'd like to allow my users to enter their phone number as a validated text field so I can incorporate it around the site.

I've [checked the docs](http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/the-basics/validation/), and its looks like I can write my own custom validation.

I tried adding the HTML5 attribute `type="tel"` to the input field without success.

Googling turns up no results.

I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?page=2&tab=oldest#tab-top) on using regex for phone # validation.

Has anyone used Redux Framework and incorporated phone # validation?

Comment: You would have to make your own custom validation or enqueue javascript to do the job. It wouldn't be hard to do though...

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to do. You'd just need to make your own custom validation class.

Take any of the Redux validation classes: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/blob/master/ReduxCore/inc/validation/numeric/validation_numeric.php

Change the class name. Include it in your code BEFORE you run Redux, and add the validation.

When it's working, submit a pull request and we'll put it in the Redux core.  :)